# Transmit pickle bytes over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, pickle

I am trying to launch a python script remotely on a server from another python script on my computer. The goal is to transmit over SSH some data which are in a class (for instance, data is the string I want to transmit. Sure it has no sense to use pickle for a string, it is juste for the example).

I would like something like that :

Script (on computer): maCo is a SSH connexion.

```
import pickle
data = 'é&'
data_bytes = pickle.dumps(data)
maCo.sendCmd(['python3', 'serverScript.py', '-ma', data_bytes])
```

Script (on server)

```
import argparse, pickle
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-ma", "--myarg", help="Arg", type=bytes)
args = parser.parse_args()
data = pickle.loads(args.myarg)
```

I try to convert bytes to string but that was not a success.
Thanks for your help

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. What is your question or problem here.

Comment: I do not ask for a full code, just the way to do it. Sorry it was confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do from your question, but I can guess...

If you are looking for a package that will help you make a ssh connection and then ship a python object, `pathos` has the ability to establish a ssh-tunnel or a direct ssh connection -- then you can pipe whatever type of communications you want through it (typically a socket-to-socket communication, like `zmq` provides, or some other `rpc` connection -- I often use `parallelpython`).  All the communications across the wire can be pickled, but they just have to be serialized objects, really.  `pathos` tries to give you a functional interface to work with ssh and parallel `pipe` and `map` constructs.

Also if you are looking to transmit a class object or a class instance, and you are using `pickle` to serialize your objects, you'll need to have the class defined in a module that already lives on the remote computer and is on the remote `PYTHONPATH`. If you use `dill` to serialize your class object or instance, you don't need the class on the remote system ahead of time.  This is because `pickle` serializes classes by reference, while `dill` can store the entire class object or instance (*or* serialize by reference).

Get `pathos` and `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

I believe `IPython` has recently been able to do some of this too, but you'll still need `dill` most likely for sending a serialized class instance (as noted above).

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I want to do, thank you.
Dill works great but pathos seems to be only compatible with python2.

Comment: Correct. `pathos` is still just `python2`, however I have converted the `pathos` fork of `parallelpython` to `python3`, so that would get you everything but the `ssh-tunnel` part.  I think `IPython` might be able to cover the rest of it in `python3`.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike ! Speak to you soon.